# AngularJS How To Manage checkbox only in the controller.js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to manage and save the checkbox value (object) only in the controllers.js?

Thanks in advance.

I have this HTML-code (entity is an object):

```
<table> 
  <tr data-ng-repeat="entity in entities">
    <td> <input type='checkbox' ng-click="toggleChecked(entity)"> {{entity.name}}</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
<pre>{{selectedBoxes|json}}</pre>
```

in my controllers.js I did this:

```
$scope.selectedBoxes = [];
$scope.toggleChecked = function(entity) { 
  if ($scope.selectedBoxes.length > 0) { 
    for (var box in $scope.selectedBoxes) { 
      if (box.name == entity.name) {
        $scope.selectedBoxes.splice(box, 1);
        return;
      }
    }
  } else {
    $scope.selectedBoxes.push(entity);
  }
}
```

I am not able to print this `<pre>{{selectedBoxes|json}}</pre>`.

Comment: Try editing your original question to include your code.  Make sure you follow the spacing guidelines so it is in a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular method of manipulating your model actually discourages using on click to manipulate the model. 
I would suggest the following:

```
<table> 
  <tr data-ng-repeat="entity in entities">
    <td> <input ng-model="entity.checked" type='checkbox'> {{entity.name}}</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
<pre>{{selectedBoxes()| json}}</pre>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.selectedBoxes = function() { 
    var selected = [];
    for (var entity in $scope.entities) {
        if ($scope.entities[entity].checked) {
            selected.push($scope.entities[entity]);
        }
    }

    return selected;
};
```

Whenever a property on entity changes, selectedBoxes() will re-evaluate which will automatically update the html.

Comment: Angular will add one when necessary. `if(entity.checked)` will evaluate to false when the property doesn't exist. When it's added, it will be true or false depending on it's state.

Comment: If I want to use a <button ng-model="entity.checked" ng-click="toggleClick()"><button>, if it's possible in the function togglecheck to verify the value of the checked attribute?